# Typing echo %path% in cmd shows a path that I don't see on the edit environment variables menu

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables, path

I have this path to Miniconda `C:\Users\[username]\miniconda3\condabin` that shows up as the first entry when I type `echo %path%` in my `cmd.exe` but upon trying to edit it through the system environment variables and user variables and removing it, I don't see it. Does anyone know why this path doesn't seem to appear? I've searched around and I still haven't seen someone with the same kind of issue. What should I do?

Comment: Check `reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"` as well as `reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"` whether there exist `AutoRun` registry variable of type `REG_SZ` or `REG_EXPAND_SZ`. Please use [edit] button to share above results in your question.

Comment: BTW, try formatting `echo %path%` as `echo %path:;=&echo.%` or even as `echo [%path:;=]&echo.[%]` 